# What should I do with broken leafs?

Tags: identification, plant-health, pruning

Some of the leafs on this plant (not sure the name!) are injured. I'm not sure if I should leave them be, cut off the damaged portion, or remove the stem from the base?[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is philodendron selloum which probably has a different botanical name now.  It is actually an oversized climber which grows aerial roots which attach to supports.  Just trim whatever part of the leaf goes brown.  No need to take off the whole leaf.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the plant is a cut-leaf philodendron (Monstera deliciosa) and the leaves are supposed to look like that. Here's a link with care instructions and photo: http://www.healthyhouseplants.com/index.php/plant-of-the-month/split-leaf-philodendron.html.